# Angular 2 Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have one router-outlet in my app.html .problem is i have 3 (post,admin,addposts)component except app.component .in my posts component i have dropdown menu onece i click dropdown i want load addposts and the url should be look like this post/addposts. any idea how to do this

this is my app.routes.ts

```
   const routes: Routes = [

      { path: '',  redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'main', component:AdminBodyComponent  },
      { path: 'admin', component:AdminComponent  },
      { path: 'posts',component:PostsComponent},
      { path: 'addposts',component:AddPostComponent}];
```

Comment: Please add punctuation and correct capitalization and spacing to your question. Also, please put the actual question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first install router via: npm install router

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


export const router: Routes = [
   { path: '',  redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'main', component:AdminBodyComponent  },
  { path: 'admin', component:AdminComponent  },
  { path: 'posts',component:PostsComponent},
  { path: 'addposts',component:AddPostComponent}];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
step2:
inject into your .ts file
constructor(
  private router:Router,
  ...
)
step3:
this.router.navigate(['/addposts']);

step4:
<base href="/">
```

if you want to use specific router go for this
step4:

Answer (score 1):

Oprion 1:

If you can add an anchor tag that will be simplest.

```
<a routerLink="/addposts" routerLinkActive="active">Add Post</a>
```

Option 2:

Follow these 3 simple steps.

**Step 1: Import the angular router**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

**Step 2: Inject the value using dependency injection**

```
constructor(
      private router:Router,
      ...
)
```

**Step 3: Invoke the navigate() inside your click event**

this.router.navigate(['/addposts']);

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to navigate to a different page because you want to route to `post/addposts`. Then you can just change your path to this

```
{ path: 'post/addposts',component:AddPostComponent}];
```

I might be wrong and you might want to use multiple router-outlet instead.